# Rails Jquery Throwing Strange Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get Jquery to work on a static portfolio website.

My code is

**home.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to navigation_main_path(format: :js), remote: true do %>
<h2> ENTER SITE </h2>
<% end %>
```

**navigation_controller.rb**

```
class NavigationController < ApplicationController

  def home     

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html 
    end

  end

  def main

  end

end
```

**format.js.erb** (for testing) in app/views/navigation

```
alert('hi');
```

**Error I believe is stopping anything from working**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < at processResponse
>   (rails-ujs.self-661556f443fbae7f6cec8f2cd394aa5e8186cb3f96aded9628126d3484eaa71a.js?body=1:246)
>   at
>   rails-ujs.self-661556f443fbae7f6cec8f2cd394aa5e8186cb3f96aded9628126d3484eaa71a.js?body=1:173
>   at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange
>   (rails-ujs.self-661556f443fbae7f6cec8f2cd394aa5e8186cb3f96aded9628126d3484eaa71a.js?body=1:230)

It is telling me there is an unexpected token on the firstline of my HTML with DOCTYPE and I have no clue why and my format.js.erb code does not run. Thank you for the help

Comment: When Rails pre-compiles its assets (css, js, etc...) it removes all whitespaces to make the code load faster. This is why it is telling you the error is on the first line, becaue the *entire script* is in the first line! Also I notice that the syntax error is being thrown from rails-ujs, not from your script. This likely means rails-ujs is misused somewhere... (and *not* that rails-ujs is the problem)

Comment: Thanks Darius, do you have any idea where rails-ujs is being misused? Also is the path of my format.js.erb file correct?

Answer (score 0):

Actually,  `format.js.erb` *is* in the wrong place!

As per Rails naming convention, the resource names for controllers and views should be **plural**. Rails is expecting `NavigationsController` and `views/navigations/format.js.erb`

More info on naming convention [here](https://gist.github.com/iangreenleaf/b206d09c587e8fc6399e)

Hope this helps!